# htmlagilitypack and httpclient using two foreach statements

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, html-agility-pack

Windows Phone 8.0 Silverlight App.

I have the following code in my MainPage.xaml.cs...

```
    protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        string htmlPage = "";
        string htmlPage2 = "";
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            htmlPage = await client.GetStringAsync("http://page1");
            htmlPage2 = await client.GetStringAsync("http://page2");
        }

        HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDocument.LoadHtml(htmlPage);

        foreach (var div in htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[starts-with(@id, 'p66acd000')]"))
        {
            GameDeals newGameDeals = new GameDeals();
            newGameDeals.dealTitle = div.SelectSingleNode(".//h2//a").InnerText.Trim();
            newGameDeals.dealCover = div.SelectSingleNode("(.//img)[1]").Attributes["src"].Value;
            newGameDeals.dealPriceText = div.SelectSingleNode(".//a[@class= 'GExclusive']").InnerText.Trim();
            newGameDeals.dealPriceGold = div.SelectSingleNode(".//span[@class= 'GPrice ProductPrice']").InnerText.Trim();
            newGameDeals.dealPriceSilver = div.SelectSingleNode(".//span[@class= 'SPrice ProductPrice']").InnerText.Trim();
            gameDeals.Add(newGameDeals);
        }
        lstGameDeals.ItemsSource = gameDeals;

        HtmlDocument htmlDocument2 = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDocument2.LoadHtml(htmlPage2);

        foreach (var div in htmlDocument2.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[starts-with(@class, 'copyContainer')]"))
        {
            GameDeals newGameDeals = new GameDeals();
            newGameDeals.dealTitle = div.SelectSingleNode(".//h4").InnerText.Trim();
            newGameDeals.dealCover = div.SelectSingleNode("(.//img)[1]").Attributes["src"].Value;
        }
        lstGameDeals.ItemsSource = gameDeals;
    }
```

I retrieve data from both pages, however, the contents of page2 do no get passed over to the lstGameDeals in my MainPage.xaml.  Am I able to use two foreach, or is there something else I am doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After the second foreach you set the ItemsSource of `lstGameDeals` with `gameDeals` variable , but i think you want to use `newGameDeals`. try `lstGameDeals.ItemsSource = newGameDeals ;` after second foreach.

Comment: Thanks Kyur, that wasn't the issue but you jogged my mind into what was wrong.  I missed the following code from the end of the second foreach.. gameDeals.Add(newGameDeals);